# application properties for different string connection to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

this is my applciation.properties for development environment

```
# thymeleaf
spring.thymeleaf.cache = false

# datasource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db
spring.datasource.username=user_for_development
spring.datasource.password=my_password_for_development
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

and this production environment :

```
# thymeleaf
spring.thymeleaf.cache = false

# datasource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db
spring.datasource.username=user_for_production
spring.datasource.password=my_password_for_production
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

if I run 'mvn package' my project to jar, using application.properties for development, its running well but this jar doesn't work in server production because different string connection to mysql.

Comment: Are you asking how to have different properties for prod vs dev?

Comment: how to build my application for production environment, using application.properties for production.

Comment: thank all, I use application.properties for production then I run " mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true package" so far my jar is running well on my server production

Answer (score 0):

I don't ever package a properties file in my jar. Part of deployment is to copy the correct properties file onto the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple different profiles for Maven forf development, QA, production etc.  See [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hold your properties file inside a jar file, I suggest using maven filtering via maven resource plugin, where you can place required values into placeholders according to profile you choose: e.g. development or production. It looks like the following:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>path/to/resource/folder</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>yourfile.properties</include>
        </includes>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

All the placeholders will be replaced by the maven properties if they exist.

Actually you can use it even you have properties file outside the jar/war file.

Answer (score 0):

You could have specific folders with properties by environment:
src/main/resources and src/main/resources-prod. Then with [Maven resources plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html)
 and [Maven profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html) you can include the correct resources in the war/jar etc.